# Почему не работает код в then?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Делаю запрос на сервер, после получения ответа хочу вызвать свое событие `change-state` и передать его в родительский компонент. Но ничего не происходит.

```js
this.axios.post('/api/v1.0/word/create/', {
  'word': this.word,
  'translate': this.translate,
  'context': this.context
})
.then((response)=>{
  console.log(response);
  this.$emit('change-state', 'default');
});
```

Response в консоль печатается.

Если вынести эту строчку за пределы всей функции, то она работает, но не дожидается ответа:

```js
this.axios.post('/api/v1.0/word/create/', {
  'word': this.word,
  'translate': this.translate,
  'context': this.context
})

this.$emit('change-state', 'default');
```

Почему это событие не срабатывает внутри then?

UPD: Проект учебный и почти пустой, залил его на гитхаб:
https://github.com/kkomissarov/anki

Comment: Чисто из любопытства, а `this` точно `vue`?

Comment: видимо `this` внутри then (а точнее колбэк функции) указывает именно на scope функции, а не VUE.

Comment: @СергейМишин вот поэтому и спросил)

Comment: @СергейМишин возможно, но как это происходит и как тогда правильно вызывать $emit, я в js не силен)

Comment: Консоль `this` сделайте

Comment: @СергейМишин насколько я понял, стрелочная функция не должна менять контекст

Comment: Конечно не должна, но мы то не видим весь код.

Comment: @doox911 вывел в консоль this. Вывелось `VueComponent`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98962/discussion-between-doox911-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что в момент, когда выполняется `then`, в `this` содержится несуществующий компонент. На самом деле, по моему вопросу это нельзя было понять, т.к. не приведен код компонентов.